# How LFW dataset used for evaluating facenet model

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, face-recognition

I am building a face recognition model using facenet. I could in most of the papers, LFW is used for validation. Trying to understand how LFW is used for validation as it has only 1600 classes with more than 2 images out of 5400 classes. Trying to find answers for the following questions

1) For validation, do we need to use only the classes with more than 1 image and neglect the remaining class ?

2) In the below link there are files under the name 'pairs.txt' and 'people.txt'. How is it exactly used ?

http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/

Answer (score 0):

To prepare a flipped dataset as a query dataset

You can use original lfw as a reference dataset, and flip it as a query dataset.

check this repo for detail [https://github.com/ZhaoJ9014/face.evoLVe.PyTorch/blob/master/util/extract_feature_v1.py](https://github.com/ZhaoJ9014/face.evoLVe.PyTorch/blob/master/util/extract_feature_v1.py#L82).

the author also gave [extract_feature_v2.py](https://github.com/ZhaoJ9014/face.evoLVe.PyTorch/blob/master/util/extract_feature_v2.py#L45) which adding centre crop before flip.